# Python Text RPG: How to Save/Load

Tags: python

Please forgive me in advance if I'm doing this wrong, I'm an absolute beginner to both programming and stack overflow. I'm using Python 3.8.3 to create a text RPG, and I'm happy with how it's turning out so far. However, I've reached the point where I need to add a save/load game feature. The game works just fine, but as expected, it wipes all progress every time you run the program.

Here is my start menu where the Load option needs to go:

```
game_start = True
print("Welcome to my RPG!")
while game_start == True:
    start_menu = int(input("Would you like to 1) Start a New Game 2) Load a previous game, or 3) Quit? "))
    if start_menu == 1:
        print("Let's begin the adventure!")
        game_start = False
    elif start_menu == 2:
        print("I'd load a game but this hasn't been implemented yet.")
    elif start_menu == 3:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Please choose 1, 2, or 3. ")
```

And here is where the save game option would go:

```
# Town menu
def town():
    town_menu = "You're in town. Command? \n"
    town_menu += "(i)nn, back to (c)ombat, (w)eapon shop, a(r)mor shop, (d)isplay stats, (e)quip, (s)ave game, (q)uit game\n"
    combat_active = False
    in_town = True
    while in_town:
        # Prompt  for command in town
        town_choice = input(town_menu)
        if town_choice == 'q':
            quit_game()
        elif town_choice == 's':
            print("I'd save but I don't know how to program that yet.")
```

Any help would be appreciated. I started programming 3 weeks ago so this is all new to me. Thanks!

Edit: here are the stats and lists I think need to be carried over when returning:

```
# Initial Stats
hero = {
    'name': char_name,
    'max_health': 15,
    'current_health': 15,
    'max_mana': 0,
    'current_mana': 0,
    'exp': 0,
    'strength': 7,
    'agility': 5,
    'resilience': 2,
    'level': 1,
    'gold': 120,
    'tier' : 1,
}

# Inventory here
inventory = {
#   'medicinal herb': 2,
#   'goblin ear': 3,
    }

equipped_weapon = weapon
equipped_armor = armor
equipped_shield = shield

# Equipped list
equipped = {
    'weapon' : equipped_weapon,
    'armor' : equipped_armor,
    'shield' : equipped_shield,
    }
```

The values listed in this code are the initial seed values. They change over time as the game goes on.

2nd edit: Thanks to John, I think his code suggestion is working. Here's the final relevant code:

```
import json # At the top
    # In start menu
    elif start_menu == 2:
        print("Loading game...")
        with open('hero.json') as infile:
            hero = json.load(infile)
        with open('inventory.json') as infile:
            inventory = json.load(infile)
        with open('equipped.json') as infile:
            equipped = json.load(infile)
        game_start = False
        new_game = False

if new_game == True:
   # seed the hero, inventory, equipped stats for a new game

# Saving game in town
        elif town_choice == 's':
            print("Saving game...")
            hero
            with open('hero.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(hero, outfile)
            inventory
            with open('inventory.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(inventory, outfile)
            equipped
            with open('equipped.json', 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(equipped, outfile)
```

Comment: What sort of data do you need to save?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What data do you want to store and recall? You can [pickle/serialize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) objects, store data as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or a database. I'd recommend starting with JSON if you're not sure, but likely you'll want to learn about dicts if you haven't yet. If you want the most immediate possible route, just [write it to/read from](https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/) file in some custom format.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for the quick response. I'll post all the code I think is relevant to retaining when returning in the main post. Gimme a few.

Comment: I think you should look a bit about [Object-Oriented Programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Say you have a `Player` object which has a `location` field (and others if you want to implement inventory, money, etc) which represents the current location of your player (so you would have to do `Location` objects too), and you would have a method to save your `Player` object in a particular format (could be simple text in txt file or in json file) and another method to recreate your `Player` object from the saved format.

Comment: I updated the post with the relevant code. ggorlen, I have seen pickle and json files mentioned elsewhere, but I don't know anything about them yet. If you have a guide/tutorial on how to add them to python programs, I could definitely use it.

NoeXWolf, I agree that that sounds very convenient. There's no way I can do that in Python though, is there? I chose Python because I'm a Network Administrator and I've heard Python scripting could help me advance my career. That being said, I'm certainly open to porting this game to other languages later!

Comment: @FreyasChosen thats exactly what pyton is for. Python is an OOP language, look into classes and how to utilize the power of Object Oriented and itll make your life much easier, and game much better

Comment: Oh, Ok. Thanks, Itai, I wasn't aware of that. I've still got a lot to learn, but this program is so close to functional, I got excited and wanted to see it through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think json would be a good choice for this.

Saving code:

```
import json
hero = {
    'name': 'fred',
    'max_health': 100,
    # etc.
}
with open('hero.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(hero, outfile)
```

Loading code:

```
import json
with open('hero.json') as infile:
    hero = json.load(infile)
```

Then you would use very similar code to save/load the inventory, equipped items, etc.

Comment: Thanks John, I'm trying this in my program right now. To be clear since I'm a newbie: I only need one 'import json' line at the beginning of my program, right? Or do I put it in both the save and the load sections?

Comment: You only need it once (assuming the save/load code is in the same file).

Comment: Thanks again! I added the code and it appears to be working (added to post as well)